# Eclipse E4 RCP application and Dynamic Services

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am upgrading an RCP application to the 4.4 (Luna) framework from 3.7 (Indigo).  The application works correctly in 3.7 but fails in 4.4 with org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access.

There are Dynamic Services (DS) that start an application service to provide access to a database.  When I remove the DS references from the manifests, the application starts, although won't fully function without the DS.

To date, I have tried changing the start order / priority of the bundles that create and use the DS but this did not correct the issue.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with troubleshooting and resolving this issue?

***UPDATE***

Tracing through the error, it fails during creation of the E4 workbench in the method Display.checkDevice().

**Full stack trace**

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getHighContrast(Display.java:1864)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.setCSSContextVariables(E4Application.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.easa.acmotor.base.Application.start(Application.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: For a start show us the full stack trace

Comment: The stack trace looks like you are using an Eclipse 3.x style Application and then trying to run the e4 application/workbench from that which isn't going to work. You must either run the org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application to use the e4 style or stick completely to the old Eclipse 3.x style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with Dynamic Services.

After several long debug sessions, the root cause was determined by placing a break in the constructor of the Display object.  That allowed us to find some very old code in the Activator of one of the plugins that executed Display.getDefault().  In 3.7 the Activator was called after the Display was initialized, in 4.4 this timing changed so the Activator was called before the application initialized the Display.